# MAX (Transact-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm starting to learn SQL and have the query below. It pulls the data I need but it is not pulling the max `benmon`, instead it is showing all months. Any suggestions?

```
select distinct a.casenum+a.type as AG, a.casenum, d.access_number,d.action,d.dateReceived, a.type, b.region, b.admin, b.unit, b.PAS, a.received, a.due, a.timestd, a.dayspend, a.dayspend-a.timestd as BeyondStd, b.imagedate, d.localUse,e.benmon,e.yyyymm
into #temp131
FROM AMS.dbo.pendingactions a, AMS.dbo.cases_daily b, AMS.dbo.ags_daily c, sandbox.dbo.workitems17 d, datamart.dbo.fsissue17 e
where a.item='APPL' and a.casenum=b.casenum and a.casenum+a.type=c.ag and a.casenum=d.casenum and a.casenum=e.casenum
AND b.admin='88126' and b.region='SC' and d.status <> 'app dis' 
  GO
update #temp131 set BeyondStd='' where BeyondStd<1
  GO
select region, admin,unit,PAS,casenum,access_number,action,max(benmon),yyyymm, type,dateReceived,received, due, timestd, dayspend, beyondstd, imageDate, localuse 
from #temp131  group by region, admin,unit,PAS,casenum,access_number,action,benmon,yyyymm, type,dateReceived,received, due, timestd, dayspend, beyondstd, imageDate, localuse
```

Comment: What is your RDBMS? Please add it as a tag.

Comment: Please also format the code in your question - right now it's very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `benmon` from your GROUP BY clause.

Generally, any column you're applying an aggregate to (MIN, MAX, COUNT, SUM, etc.) is not needed in the GROUP BY.

Comment: It is still pulling all months available for that case #. I appreciate the help, tomorrow Ill find out the answer. Thank you

Comment: In that case, there must be an additional field which has multiple values for that case number. You can either remove these fields from the SELECT and GROUP BY, or aggregate them somehow. Or if you want to list multiple records for each case number, and just show the maximum benmonth for every record, you can use a CTE. If you can show some sample data and desired output, then it would be easier to improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing each month because of all the fields in your group by clause.  The group by will basically rollup all of the unique combinations of ALL the fields and then apply the aggregation.  So in your group by:

```
group by region, admin,unit,PAS,casenum,access_number,action,benmon,yyyymm, type
```

you have yyyymm and benmon as two of the fields.  So it will create "groups" for each month. Depending on how unique the rest of the fields are that is how unique the group will be.